# Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets error?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, unset

Not sure why this is occurring: Basically, I have an array that contains the following arrays, see `var_dump`:

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "ivr" 
  } 
  [1]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(9) "ivr_dests" 
  } 
}
```

Obviously this data is kind of redundant, but it's what was returned while getting values with xpath. So I'm doing a `foreach` to loop through the first `array()` and assign it's nested array values in the first array.

Basically, it should return this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(3) "ivr"
  [1]=> string(9) "ivr_dests"
}
```

So here is what I've setup:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $arr2){
    $arr2[$key] = $arr2[$key][0];
    unset($arr2[$key][0]); //This returns Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets
//if I comment out the unset(), $arr[$key] returns the same value as it did (multidim array)
};

        //I tried this too:
$i=0;
foreach($arr as $arr2){
  $arr2[$i] = $arr2[$i][0];
  $i++;
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Should I go about this another way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the unset, you are overriding the outer parameters with the value of the inner array as opposed to the whole array.

```
$a1 = array("ivr");
$a2 = array("ivr2");

$a3 = array($a1, $a2);

foreach($a3 as $key => $value){
    $a3[$key] = $a3[$key][0];
    //unset($arr2[$key][0]);
};

var_dump($a3);
```

I think you are confused about how foreach works.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  echo $key;
  echo $value;
}
```

will display the key and value for each key/value pair in an array.

Comment: That makes sense. Part of my confusion was that I unset an array earlier, but I realize now I was creating a new array and unsetting the old one, not overwriting one like this example. You're example helps me make sense of `foreach()` too, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I had this error in a slightly different situation which might prove useful.

```
unset($search['param']['complete'])
```

This threw the same error when $search['param'] was still a **string** instead of an **array**.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you try to unset a string value - In below case you access the first element in the array which is a string and the try to unset it which causes this error

```
$a=array("hello", "there");
unset($a[0][0]);
```

This causes:

```
Fatal error:  Cannot unset string offsets in ... on line ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you have the syntax for the `foreach` wrong...it should be `$key => $value` where you have `$key => $arr2`. So when you have `$arr2[$key]` you are looking for element `$key` in the nested array `$arr2`. `$arr2` is referenced by `$key`, which is either a string (for an associative array) or an integer (for a non-associative array). `$arr2` could also be referenced by `$arr[$key]`.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the code.
After you assign

```
$arr2[$key] = $arr2[$key][0];
```

`$arr2[$key]` becomes the string `"ivr"` and `$arr2[$key][0]` is the first character of the string and can't be unset

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Use only array key to unset, not it's value. Example:

`$fruits = ['a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'orange', 'c' => 'banana'];`

if you try `unset($fruits['a]['apple'];`, you will face this error. Correct usage `unset($fruits['a];`